"Couldn't complete your purchase. Check that you have the correct country selected in your Play account." error on Play Store - when region is India
trying to make in app game purchases and play store displays "Couldn't complete your purchase. Check that you have the correct country selected in your Play account." error. changed country removed payment profile and created new one. tried everything possible but still shows the same error. Country living in is India and location is already set to India, yet i still get this message. this was only from the past few days, I never had this issue earlier over the years.
can someone advise or hep me in this regard.
Play store version 41.5.29-31 [0][pr].
Android OS 14.0

Possible dupe: "Couldn't complete your purchase. Check that you have the correct country selected in your Play account." error on Play Store

Does this answer your question? "Couldn't complete your purchase. Check that you have the correct country selected in your Play account." error on Play Store

The country is accurate and is showing as India, where i am located. This problem cropped up suddenly a few days ago, i deleted my payment profile, created a new one yet same problem
